# How to sync folders in Ubuntu 16.04 on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-16.04

I want to do a two directional sync between /var/www/html/data and /var/www/data so that if there are changes on any of those folder they are automatically the same automatically. what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to create a [symbolic link](https://kb.iu.edu/d/abbe).

```
ln -s /var/www/html/data /var/www/data
```

This will basically expose the same content in different paths, but the content is the same. In many cases when deploying web apps normally a [symlink](https://lornajane.net/posts/2010/one-step-symlink-switch) is created after the deploy process has finished.

If you want duplicated copies you could use [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync).

```
rsync -av /var/www/html/data /var/www/data
```